# If a matrix is written with a double bar instead of square brackets, is there any significance?

Tags: matrices, notation

Shilov's Linear Algebra writes a matrix with two bars on each side rather than square brackets. I didn't find any mention of it with a quick Google search, and I can't see any other examples this double bar notation.

Does it mean something other than a matrix? Is it an older notation? Or is it something else?

Thank you

Comment: I think your interpretation of the notation is correct. Single bars, on the other hand, seem to denote a determinant.

Comment: Yes, it's a matrix (he uses double bars where most other people would use parentheses or brackets). Look at the definition [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=5U6loPxlvQkC&pg=PA5).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like he means a matrix when he uses double bars:

[image]

He uses the standard notation for a determinant, i.e. single bars:

[image]

I don't know if his notation for matrices was something that was common at the time he wrote the book, but I don't think it's popular now.

Comment: Perhaps it is (was?) a Russian thing? It's also used in Gantmacher's *The Theory of Matrices*, for example.

Comment: Ah, that sounds like it could very well be the reason.

Comment: Yeah, he made it clear that it was a matrix. But not being able to find a reference to the notation anywhere else was a bit disconcerting. Thanks!